# Deep Link - Https unexpectedly redirecting to chrome

Tags: android, kotlin, oauth, deep-linking

I am working on adding an OAuth flow to a Trello integration within my app. The idea is using deep linking to consume the response within the app itself (there is no server between the app and the database - I am using room).

I have everything working up to this point except the callback redirect portion, and it works on my real device, rather than the emulator.

This is the code that begins the OAuth flow.

```
val connection = object:CustomTabsServiceConnection() {
        override fun onCustomTabsServiceConnected(name: ComponentName, client: CustomTabsClient) {
            val builder = CustomTabsIntent.Builder()
            val customTabsIntent = builder.build()
            client.warmup(0)
            var authUrl = "$TOKEN_URL?key=$API_KEY&scope=read&callback_method=fragment&return_url=${AuthenticationManager.HTTPS_REDIRECT_URL}&expiration=never&name=$NAME&integration=${integration.id}"
            customTabsIntent.launchUrl(context, Uri.parse(authUrl))
        }
        override fun onServiceDisconnected(name: ComponentName?) {
        }
    }
    bindCustomTabsService(context, "com.android.chrome", connection);
```

Manifest

```
 <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.MainActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="sensor"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="uiMode">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="pomodoro" android:host="oauth.myapp.com"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

At this point it is redirected to my webpage, which I verified on my real device redirects to my app (so it can consume the intent and get the necessary token). I am wondering if when I selected Always use for the chrome browser (when initially opening a webpage in the emulator), that this basically overrides my deep link? Is that possible? Also using a different scheme isn't possible, as Trello forces uses to use https/http as the trusted redirect/callback urls?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is related to my misunderstanding of deeplinks vs AppLinks. I want to treat this more as an AppLink vs a deeplink, meaning the verification has already happened that this URL belongs to my app (via a file on my domain). For this verification to happen I need the verification file at the appropriate url, if it is not there - the verification cannot happen. Which happens for each host/scheme, and must verify all match.

The solution was to remove the scheme/host that isn't associated with the app/domain, to allow AutoVerify.

"Only if the system finds a matching Digital Asset Links file for all hosts in the manifest does it then establish your app as the default handler for the specified URL patterns." https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations

After updating my manifest to the below it worked as expected, and redirected the OAuth flow as expected.

```
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <data android:scheme="https" android:host="myapp.com"/>
        </intent-filter>
```